# Kendo file upload - add file description

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui

We want to add a description for each file that is being uploaded.

The requirement is to have a text box against each filename to be uploaded, where the user can key in some description about the file.

Is there any way to add a description in the multiple file upload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know such feature not available in the Kendo File Upload control.

But you can upload all files and bind them to editable Kendo Grid with description TextBox and save it.